# simple fade in function in xcode

Tags: xcode, fadein

despite my best efforts, I am failing on the code for the fade-in timing of my frame. for some reason that I cant understand, the withDuration is not fading at all.
if someone has a moment to review my code I would v much appreciate the help...

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport


let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 128, y: 128, width: 256, height: 256))
view.backgroundColor = .red
UIView.animate(withDuration: 3) {
view.alpha = 1
}

let containerView =  UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 512, height: 
512))
containerView.backgroundColor = .white
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = containerView
containerView.addSubview(view)
```

Comment: i thought that setting the view.alpha to 1 resulted in the fade in, with the duration (in this case 3) being the length in time of the fade.
so I am obviously wrong in my thinking, so how should I write it then such that it fades in please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem 1: `view.alpha` is already `1` so there is nothing to animate.

Problem 2: Order matters. Things happen in the order you command them. That order must be coherent.

So:

```
let containerView =  UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 512, height: 512))
containerView.backgroundColor = .white
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = containerView
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 128, y: 128, width: 256, height: 256))
view.alpha = 0
view.backgroundColor = .red
containerView.addSubview(view)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 3) {
    view.alpha = 1
}
```

Comment: ok thanks matt,  appreciate the clarrity.  works perfectly now.